# IDEA, package and project views, clarification needed

Tags: intellij-idea

In Project view, using IDEA12, I have 3 modules under a single project as shown:

[image]

Using the package view, i have 2 modules

[image]

- In this example, what happened to `report`?
- What are these 2 views designed to represent and when should each be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the description in [help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-tool-window.html):

- **Project view**. In this view, all the project items along with their dependencies (SDKs and libraries) are shown. The emphasis is on the directory structure (though the packages are also shown).
- **Packages view**. The emphasis is on the package structure of the project. The modules, SDKs and libraries, by default, are not shown.

There are different display options available depending on the view mode. For example you can hide module names as well in the Packages view.

`report` may not be displayed if it doesn't contain any unique packages or sources, but I can't tell for sure from the details you've provided.